# Running a mobile app in the iOS environment that was developed native in Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, cross-platform

I figured this would be an easy answer to find, however, I haven't had much luck.

I've heard of services such as Phonegap and others where the developer can develop a web app and it gets wrapped and deployed to the Windows, iOS and Android platforms. However, is there a method that you can build native to Java/Android and then wrap it to run on another mobile device platforms?

Comment: Your better bet would be to use Xamarin.  I've personally never heard of any wrapper that magically runs an Android app on multiple platforms, and I don't think it's trivial to make one or they would exist.  A lot of companies have both an iOS team and an Android team, or engineers that do both or many platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up discovering the ionic framework found [here](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/). I found it the best (and by far the easiest) route to go for cross platform development. It uses angularJS and web based implementation that wraps content for ios, android, blackberry and windows mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google's [java2objc](https://code.google.com/p/java2objc/) code conversion tool you can generate Objective C code from Java code. Google has used it to generate ~40% of the code used in their new email app Inbox so it's a reasonably proven technology.

With that said, it will *not* generate any UI related code nor should it be, as each platform has its own UI standard. What it can do is to allow you to write the business logic once and reused it for iOS.

Comment: Oh that sound so useful, I'm not sure how I haven't ran across this before. Thank you

Comment: @GarrettMacMac if you find this answers your question, please mark this as the answer, as described in [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)